# Array creation in shell with find command

Tags: shell

Hello i have the following problem: This code is runing in a shell-script without syntax error on my pc but on an other server i get a syntax error "(" unexpected

```
export data=( $(find "~/" -iname "*.png") )
for i in ${data[@]}
do
    mogrify -crop 1024x794 ${i}
    rm ${i%.png}-1.png
    mv ${i%.png}-0.png ${i}   
done
```

Comment: Not that this isn't safe for paths/files with spaces in them. Also a quoted `~` doesn't get expanded correctly so this *can't* be working at all as written here. And you don't need (or want) `export` here.

Comment: This is basically http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor with an extra layer of indirection involved: It string-splits and glob-expands names in the string returned by `find`, so the values are no longer guaranteed to be equivalent to their literals. In short, the filenames it returns can simply be wrong.

Comment: ...if you want to see this for yourself, create a file with the command `touch 'hello * world.png'` in a non-empty directory, and see what this code does in result.

Comment: ...though you have other bugs surrounding your array usage as well, so even if you fixed your `find` usage you still couldn't correctly handle filenames with spaces from this code. However, those are all quoting issues that http://shellcheck.net/ would find for you easily.

Comment: You don't need `export` here, as arrays are not exported anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure you are using Bash to execute you script. Maybe add a shebang: `#! /usr/bin/bash` in the first line of your script. You could also check this with a `echo $SHELL` command in your script. Bash version might also be different. Check with `bash --version` on the command line.

Comment: But in both ways i defined a #! /usr/bin/sh  so why does it work in one of the two programs?

Comment: Not just "maybe", and no mystery to it -- any `/bin/sh` shell promises only POSIX sh compatibility, and POSIX doesn't cover arrays, so there's no guarantee that the feature will be present. OTOH, `sh` is *allowed* to be a superset of POSIX sh, so it's also no surprise if it's provided by ksh, bash, or another shell that *does* allow arrays on some specific machine.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is not compliant with best practices -- it'll fail badly with filenames with spaces or newlines in their names. To do it right, if you have a `find` with `-print0`:

```
#!/bin/bash

data=( )
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  data+=( "$filename" )
done < <(find ~ -iname '*.png' -print0)
```

---

By the way, you don't *really* need arrays for this at all -- or even `find`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# This version DOES NOT need bash

# function to run for all PNGs in a single directory
translate_all() {
  for i in "${1:-$HOME}"/*.png; do
    mogrify -crop 1024x794 "$i"
    rm "${i%.png}-1.png"
    mv "${i%.png}-0.png" "$i"   
  done
}

# function to run for all PNGs in a single directory and children thereof
translate_all_recursive() {
  dir=${1:-$HOME}; dir=${d%/}
  translate_all "$dir"
  for d in "$dir"/*/; do
    translate_all_recursive "$d"
  done
done

# actually invoke the latter
translate_all_recursive
```

---

References:

- [BashFAQ #001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) ("How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?", showing the correct practice; search for `-print0`).
- [UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) (likewise).
- [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)
- [Don't Read Lines With For](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) (from the Wooledge wiki)